# Can someone help me deseserializer c#

Tags: c#

```
int count = deserializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
```

cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'int'. An explicit conversion exist (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Why do you think `Deserialize` would return some count?  A count of what?  What code did you use to serialize the code in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `int count = (int)deserializer.Deserialize(fileStream);`

Answer (score 0):

If it's indeed an `Int32`, you can do:

```
int count = (int)deserializer.Deserialize(fileStream);
```

Serializers don't know at compile-time what *type* they're deserializing, so the method will return an object.  You'll have to cast that object to whatever the *actual* type is.